# How to create URL to language switcher anchor with langhandler in Yii

Tags: php, yii, internationalization

I need to create language switcher button in my Yii Application with [langhandler extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/langhandler/)

So I try this:

**Input**

```
$this->createUrl($this->id.'/'.$this->action->id,array('lang'=>'en'));

echo CHtml::link('Switch Language',$url);
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="controller/action">English</a>
```

But unfortunately this is not work if I have special parameters like 'id', So how I can change 'lang' parameter and also keep other parameters ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually find this solution and this is work in all cases:

I just pushed the lang parameter to $_GET array and this is work, So please if you have better solution or any comment please share it with me.

**Input:**

```
$_GET['lang'] = 'en';
$url = $this->createUrl($this->id.'/'.$this->action->id,$_GET);
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="controller/action/id?sort=recent&lang=en">English</a>
```